# Rails number_field with Ajax

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a form having multiple fields representing an order item. I'm trying to make sure that changes made to quantity of item are saved in real time. I was able to do this when the order item is completely removed through a link_to field. I'm not able to do the same for a number_field:

My code for the 2 fields is as follows:

```
<%= order_item_form.number_field :quantity, update_quantity_path(:order_item_id => order_item.id, :quantity => order_item.quantity), remote: true, method: :patch, class: "form-control", min: 0 %>
<%= link_to 'Remove', update_quantity_path(:order_item_id => order_item.id, :quantity => 0), remote: true, method: :patch, class: "remove_fields" %>
```

So in the above, the link_to is working. When the order item is removed, the behavior is correct. 
For the number_field though, I'm getting an error `wrong number of arguments (given 3, expected 1..2)`

What am I doing wrong? How can I make the number_field work remotely with Ajax?

Comment: try `:method => 'PATCH'` instead  of`method: :patch`

Comment: Hi, did you manage to fix it?

Comment: Not yet. I'll try your suggestion today though. Hope that it works :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rails-way to do this is to add these data attributes to your `number_field`:

```
<%= order_item_form.number_field :quantity, class: "form-control", min: 0, data: { remote: true, method: :patch, url: update_quantity_path(order_item_id: order_item.id, quantity: 0) } %>
```

Have a look at *Customize remote elements* section in the [Working with Javascript in Rails](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html#customize-remote-elements) guide for further explanation and to learn how to disable the input field until the Ajax request returns.

Comment: Stupid question. Any ideas though how can I send the value of the number_field value instead of sending 0 here?

Comment: I basically get into the function I want though, so job done, and bounty deserved :)

Comment: Just remove the `quantity: 0` and check the `params` you then receive then in the corresponding controller action. Rails should send one automatically named after the input fields name, which is "quantity" in your case.

Answer (score 1):

The error comes because you are setting a `path` as one of the arguments to the `number_field` method.

The documentation tells us that there should only be 2 arguments when we use the method in form builders.

Example: `number_field(method, options = {})`

Rails API Doc: [Link to number_field method](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormBuilder.html#method-i-number_field)

You should use this type of arguments in `data:`

Example:

```
<%= order_item_form.number_field :quantity, data: { url: update_quantity_path(...), ... }, ... %>
```

That eliminates the error.

Comment: Hi @mrateb, Does this solution work for you? Anything, let me know.

Comment: Hi FDLC, thanks for the answer.
I tried this, its not giving an error but not working

Comment: Im trying to tweak it to see if I can get it to work

Comment: @mrateb Ok, anything, let us know.

Comment: I upvoted because helpful, this did not work unfortunately :(